# ordering UNION queries laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have two tables, each table contain created_at time stamp column,
after making union between them, i tried to make order by after union, but it's not work, so how i can order data descending according to created_at column of the two tables in Laravel ?

```
$vac = db::table("table_a")->select($arr);
    $m = db::table("table_b")->select($arr_1)->union($vac)->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in controller

```
use DB;
```

in inside controller function

```
DB::select('select ? from table_a union  select ? from table_b order_by created_at desc',[$arr,$arr_1]);
```